# Twig's dump function returns a blank screen

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using Twig's [dump](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) function in Symfony2. I have configured Symfony according to [its instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#debugging).

I have a `page` variable, and an `orders` array. `dump` works on page, but not orders. When I call it on orders, I get a white screen - no php errors or anything. I have no idea how to debug this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anything in your error log? Do you have error_reporting enabled?

Comment: I don't remember but I don't think so. One thing I did was return the data as a json response and just look at it in the inspector. But I never discovered the root cause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### A little explanation

A white (blank) screen in this case means the PHP fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted. During my investigation, I found that **twig uses the`var_dump` function** while I have VarDumper component  installed.

I think its made to work along in case the VarDumper component is not installed, but twig's `dump()` function covered in symfony's VarDumper component documentation like a complex solution, that's strange.

So, **using VarDumper's `dump()` function instead of native `var_dump()` solves the memory problem** (because VarDumper limits result dump collection to adequate amount). Also VarDumper's `dump()` give more convenient results - you can click on tree leafs to show/hide its content.

### What exactly do you need to do

- [Install VarDumper component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html) if not installed
- Go to file: `vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php`
- Find `twig_var_dump` function
- Replace all `var_dump()` calls to `dump()`
- Delete/comment `ob_start() + ob_get_clean()` construction (which is needed
  if you use `var_dump()` as it echoes data immideately, but `dump()` acting
  more intelligent)

OR

copy + replace the entire function using this:

```
function twig_var_dump(Twig_Environment $env, $context)
{
    if (!$env->isDebug()) {
        return;
    }

    $count = func_num_args();
    if (2 === $count) {
        $vars = array();
        foreach ($context as $key => $value) {
            if (!$value instanceof Twig_Template) {
                $vars[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        dump($vars);
    } else {
        for ($i = 2; $i < $count; $i++) {
            dump(func_get_arg($i));
        }
    }

}
```

PS: Question's asked in 2013, but I hope it helps because I had this problem now.

My context:

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.5.*"
"symfony/var-dumper": "~2.6"
```

Comment: you should make a pull request with this improvement on official twig repository

Comment: @Charles-AntoineFournel thats a good idea, I'll work on it in future

Comment: At the current state, I assume that symfony 3.0.9 has this functionality because I have seen dump() function working in my twig template in new freshly installed project.

Comment: @Arkemlar Unfortunately, this still occurs in Symfony 4 – the proposed fix did help.

Comment: @bleistift2 well, it seems we need to make a failing test wich will address this porblem and open PR. I wish I had time for it...

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, increasing the memory_limit up to 1Gb didn't help. 
In my case I want to call the

```
    {{ dump() }}
```

with no parameters (to see all the available vars in the context of the current template. In my case the following helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11500141/2166261 , though the memory_limit issue still persists)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are hitting your PHP memory limit. Try increasing it in the php.ini

Comment: Seems like you're right, but I don't understand how. It's just one form tied to my instance data - I've increased the limit to 200MB and still no dice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no single answer to this problem, as a range of things could cause it. As other people have suggested, increasing the memory limit for PHP may help. In my case this did not help, however, I was able to resolve the issue by installing xdebug.

So far, it seems then that a checklist for resolving this issue would look something like this:

1. Ensure that the latest version of xdebug is installed
2. If that doesn't resolve it, try increasing PHP memory limit

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It is a potential answer to the question because I had the exact same problem and this was the way it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The Arkemlar answer works fine.

BUT

after that the twig dump() caused a RuntimeException in the functional test with phpunit in my case.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.