# Symfony2 and Twig Dump Issue

Tags: symfony, error-handling, twig, dump

I am running into an issues with dump() in Twig.

I am not able to completely dump the values of the object that I am returning to my twig template. My object, as defined below, is built up of a product object, qty key/val, OnOrder key/val and avgUnitCost key/val.

I AM able to use dump(qty), dump(OnOrder), dump(avgUnitCost) and see the values of these.

I AM NOT able to use dump() on product to see the key/val of the product object. All I get is a white page of death.

I have read elsewhere on stack that it is a memory issue in the php.ini file. This does not seem to fix the issue, I set mine 1024M and it still times out and gives me the white screen.

I have also read this guys article on the same issue: http://hectorpinol.com/twig-debug-in-symfony-2/ ... He thinks it is a "bidirectional association problem".

In any case, here is the code that I am using to pass the object and render my twig template...

```
return $this->render('TestBundle:Event:view.html.twig', array(
            'heading' => 'View Product',
            'product' => $product,
            'qty' => $qty,
            'OnOrder' => $OnOrder,
            'avgUnitCost' => $avgUnitCost,
    ));
```

**Here is the guts of my question:** 
How can one effectively use twig to access the elements of an object, whether it be dump or some other method. I need to be able to see all of the elements in the object so that I can place them on the page as I need.

Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: In the context of Symfony + Twig my tests lead me to suspect it's a memory leak due to a circular reference: basically no amount of memory will be enough if memory usage spirals up infinitely. Otherwise it's just a bunch of really heavy objects being dumped.

Comment: If you try a var_dump($entity) in your controller just before rendering, Chrome displays an infinite-long page, and keeps on adding things until PHP's timeout. So yes, there must be an issue there, knowing that Twig's dump() uses var_dump internally. And yes, it's due to bidirectional relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [LadybugBundle](https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle). You can dump everything.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this bundle!

Comment: Ladybug project is abandoned https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle/issues/79

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a break point in twig_var_dump:

`/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php` (at the bottom)

Then you can use the functionality of your debugger...

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29302069/4102223

It is my approach to solve this problem, only few lines must to be changed in one place (it is easier because no need to include new bundles and read its documentation).