# How to enable Twig's dump() in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml

Seeing various threads on this topic but not finding a working answer. Have a simple Symfony2 app (2.3.5) and trying to dump variables passed into my Twig templates. I have in  my app/config/config.yml:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
```

and in my app/config/config_dev.yml:

```
services:
    twig.extension.debug:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Debug
        tags:
           - { name: twig.extension }
```

But using dump() in a twig still renders an empty page. I also increased memory limit in php.ini to 512 ... still nothing

Which part of this am I missing?

Comment: Please try to use my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14913859/4102223

Answer (score 6):

Try `class: Twig_Extension_Debug` instead. :)

Comment: Also wouldn't it be `\Twig_Extension_Debug`?

Comment: @Qoop As long as the [current namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) is the global/root namespace, it doesn't matter. "Xyz" will resolve to "\Xyz". If you were referring to a class in your own bundle, as when [defining controllers as services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) for instance, you also wouldn't normally start with a "\". Same goes for PHP's `use` statement, from what I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

In symfony2.3, this extension is automatically enabled when twig.debug is set to true, so you should be able to use the dump function.

Comment: Oh how I wish that were true. And I wish I knew why it doesn't work and I wish there was good documentation on how to set this up. As with so many things in Symfony, it's great until it doesn't work, then you are SOL. I've followed every suggestion, and dump simply does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try `{% debug var %}` as shown in this link:

http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/06/symfony2-debugging-with-twig-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

Because I didn't found the answer on the web, I will share my working solution here:

```
# app/config.yml
twig:
    debug: %kernel.debug%
```

Then in a Twig template:

```
{% dump var %}
```

Tested on Symfony 2.7